# jQuery TextboxList - add focus (select) first item in results

Tags: jquery

Is it possible when user starts to type and suggestions are shown, that the first element is selected?

Script which I'm using: http://devthought.com/projects/jquery/textboxlist/

Comment: Probably. I suggest you read the *The anatomy of TextboxList* part and try some things.

Comment: I have but I didin't found solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add this line:

```
(!options.onlyFromValues && current && current.get(0) === list.find(':first').get(0)) ? blur() : focusRelative('prev');
```

To the end of the showResults function inside of TextboxList.Autocomplete.js

Comment: I've putt and it is not working, now is code like this:
results = results;
  (!options.onlyFromValues && current && current.get(0) === list.find(':first').get(0)) ? blur() : focusRelative('prev');
 };